# Sytax error: Missing ), but I don't see it. My quotation marks don't seem to be the problem either

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax

I've been working on this app script trying to automate data from a Google sheet to create events on Google Calendar. I've tried changing the Quotation marks from single to double and back. I've checked my () over and over. I cannot see what I've done that gives me the syntax error.  If you can see it, please tell me.  This is making me nuts.

```
function AutomateCalendarEvent() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let pqCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("zyxwvutsrqp");  
  let reservation = sheet.getRange("C2:E1105").getValues();
  reservation.splice(0, 1);
  let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function (row, index)  {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[C3]) return;
    
  pqCalendar.createAllDayEvent("Last Name"C2:C, "Arrival Date"D2:D, "Departure Date"E2:E);
    
   })
}
```

Comment: I din't understand what that means `if (row[C3]) return;` as C3 is not an index

Comment: you should share a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data are as follows

[image]

Try (to prevent duplicates, the event ID is here stored in column AI fr instance)

```
function AutomateCalendarEvent() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let swCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("***********@gmail.com");
  let rows = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  rows.filter(row => row[2] != '').forEach(function (row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[34] == '') { // AI
      try {
        sheet.getRange('AI' + (+index + 1)).setValue(swCalendar.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row[3], row[4]).getId())
      } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
    }
  })
}
```

### reference

[createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate, {options})](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createalldayeventtitle,-startdate,-enddate,-options)

[image]

Comment: Last Name Arrival Date Departure Date
McDonald          4/28/2022    4/30/2022
Doe                  5/3/2022            5/6/2022
Barr                  5/13/2022    5/15/2022
Jones          5/18/2022    5/21/2022

Comment: I tried what you said and got this Error message: Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createAllDayEvent. (line 10, file "Code")

Comment: function AutomateCalendarEvent() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let swCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("strongwaterbc@gmail.com");  
  let reservation = sheet.getRange("C2:E1105").getValues();
  reservation.splice(0, 1);
  let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function (row, index)  {
    if (index === 0) return;
        
  swCalendar.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row [3], row[4]);
    
   })
}

Comment: I have updated my answer. Pls share a spreadsheet if you want to adapt

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIihFrlGiTRiaIg_AOabcSujcIxcrLS10QRVPB1WGlY/edit#gid=1363297816

Comment: access denied ...i have asked for access ... however I have updated my answer as I imagine your data

Comment: You were correct.  I'm sorry. I don't know how to share the database.  I tried your suggestion and 1st got:TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadSheet is not a function (line 3, file "Code")   so I removed .getActiveSpreadSheet and 2nd error: Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.createEvent. (line 6, file "Code")

Comment: I know the parameters are supposed to be (title, startDate, endDate).  How do I get the code to know that the last two rows[] are dates?

Comment: I just checked the calendar and the events all showed up, even with my being unable to save or run the code without errors???

Comment: I don't use getActiveSpreadSheet in this piece of code ! can you delete the events in your agenda and retry with the code above from your script editor?

Comment: If the dates are entered correctly, the script will retrieve them as dates. But be aware that sometimes they look like dates but are text. If so we have to adapt the script.

Comment: It is working! Yay!  Thank you!  I would like Google calendar to autofill each time there's a new row in the sheet.  Is that possible?

Comment: yes, first of all you will have to flag each row already trabsform in an event inside your calendar, the best way is to put the id that teh script will return, have you a free column to do that? A, B, F? and then we will have to check during the script which row has an empty "flag"

Comment: Column AI is open.  The other thing is that when I run my code, it adds another event on the calendar so there are copies of each row. (ie. there are two McDonald reservations on the same days)

Comment: I have updated my answer. The event ID will be stored in column AI and this column will be tested to prevent any duplicates.

Comment: I added a new row in the sheet and ran the script.  I got doubles of the events that had been applied previously.  Tried it a couple of times, clearing the calendar and running the script, adding a row, and running it again...duplicates.

Comment: I got it working.  Your script was right.  Thank you! You were using coding beyond my knowledge.  Couldn't have done it without you., Mike!

Comment: Hi Mike,  I need your help again.  I took several columns out.  So I changed if  (row[34] == ' ') {  // AI  to   if (row[29]==' ') {  // AD.  I changed sheet.getRange('AI')... to sheet.getRange('AD').  And because I wanted to have the location show up in the calendar with the name and dates, I added to row[14], and row[16], like this: .setValue(swCalendar.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row[3], row[4], row[14], row[16].getID()).  Now it won't work.  What did I miss?

Comment: what are the informations in columns O (row[14]) and Q (row[16])? if O is description and Q location, you can try `sheet.getRange(+index + 1, col).setValue(swCalendar.createAllDayEvent(row[0], row[1], row[2], { description: row[14], location: row[16] }).getId())`

Comment: Both O and Q are locations.  I need to keep them separate on the sheet, but on the calendar, either or both need to show up.  I tried your code , but adding two locations...that didn't work.      Sorry I took so long getting back.  Went away for a few days. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: let swCalend = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("strongwaterbc@gmail.com");
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    let rows = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    rows.filter(row => row[2] != '').forEach(function (row, index) {
      if (index === 0) return;
      if (row[28] == '') { // AC
        try {
          
          sheet.getRange(+index + 1, col).setValue(swCalend.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row[3], row[4], { location:[14], location:[16] }).getID())
             } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
      }
    })
   
}

Comment: `try { sheet.getRange(+index + 1, col).setValue(swCalend.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row[3], row[4], { location:row[14]+' '+row[16] }).getID()) }`

Comment: Did I do something wrong?  It saved and ran without errors, but nothing happened in the calendar.            
    
    rows.filter(row => row[2] != '').forEach(function (row, index) {
      if (index === 0) return;
      if (row[28] == '') { // AC 
        try { 
          sheet.getRange(+index + 1,col).setValue(swCalend.createAllDayEvent(row[2], row[3], row[4], { location:row[14]+' '+row[16] }).getID()) 
        }  catch (e) { console.log(e) }
      
    }
  })
}

Comment: please, share again your spreadsheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIihFrlGiTRiaIg_AOabcSujcIxcrLS10QRVPB1WGlY/edit?userstoinvite=mike.steelson@gmail.com&actionButton=1#gid=1363297816.  I've shared it with you.

Comment: what means AC column for you ? do you intend to fill it when the agenda has been updated? if so we need to fill in the forme response tab since you have a query function

Comment: i have corrected, please try (and delete rows between 100 and 50500, your spreadsheet is awfully heavy) If you need you can email me!

Comment: I see the locations listed in the calendar schedule.  How do I email you? This has brought a new problem. I need to ensure that the cabins and sites are not double-booked on the same dates.

Answer (score 0):

#### Take a look at my comments

```
function AutomateCalendarEvent() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let pqCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("zyxwvutsrqp");  
  let reservation = sheet.getRange("C2:E1105").getValues();
  reservation.splice(0, 1);
  let rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function (row, index)  {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[C3]) return;//C3 should be an index between 0 and 2
    
  pqCalendar.createAllDayEvent("Last Name"C2:C, "Arrival Date"D2:D, "Departure Date"E2:E);//parameters should be a string followed by two dates
    //this is not the way insert parameters into above command.  Ranges do not return values
   })
}
```

Comment: The string and the dates are coming from the Sheet.  "Last Name" from column C is the title (string) and the dates are in columns D and E in the sheet.  How else am I supposed to get them to the calendar?

Comment: Get them from the row